# Form gets bigger after saving size and location properties

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Something is wrong with how settings are being saved/read from in Windows Forms apps.

It's not a problem with my code. But I don't know what's wrong.

```
Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Size = new Size(Properties.Settings.Default.Size.Width, Properties.Settings.Default.Size.Height);
   this.Location = new Point(Properties.Settings.Default.Location.X, Properties.Settings.Default.Location.Y);
}

Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Location = this.Location;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Size = this.Size;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Now. You can see that the code is right.

**Why then, does the Form get bigger and Bigger and BIgger and BIGger and BIGGer and BIGGEr and BIGGER every single time I reopen my app?**

It's supposed to stay the same size! You know, since I saved it and everything... Why?

Comment: That is an excessive use of **Bigger**.

Comment: Relax, mate it's all going to be ok.

Comment: Since you have already established that it's not a problem with your code, there is nothing you or we can do. You are doomed.

Comment: What you want is that the size would remain after the user has resize it right???

Comment: Are you changing the size of the form before you exit the program?

Comment: I take it you have put a breakpoint in Load and checked the values applied?

Comment: Yes, that is the whole point :-) The point is to save the size and location of the form before the user closes it, and restore it to its previous size and location when the user re-opens the app :)

Comment: @ĈħőşęņŎńę When you reach the `Form1_Closing` with the debugger, are the values of `Location` and `Size` correct ?

Comment: @sa_ddam213 Below are the values, in order of appearance. When I first run the app with rbeakpoints, it has initial values (that I have NOT set), and then by the time it fully displays the form, the values are WAY bigger: `240x49l
791x434s
-

922x716s`

Comment: @ĈħőşęņŎńę, perhaps your layout is not complet when you apply the saved Size/Location, maybe you could try the `Shown` event instead of `Load` event

Comment: btw windows form on 2012 does not have size and location in C# windows form. I think somethings wrong with vs2012

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov yeah they're correct at FormClosing time.

Comment: Is there a main form?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2013? If not, please remove the tag.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Tim the user may or may not change the size/location of the form before it's closed.

Answer (score 3):

The `Size` property includes the non-client area of the form, which can fluctuate wildly depending on whether you have enabled themes, Aero, etc.

Try using the `ClientSize` property instead.

Comment: I think so too he not using the client size on form load

Comment: I don't get it though. This exact same code has been working flawlessly for years. Why is it only affecting _this_ app, and _only now_? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: If I use it on Form_Shown instead of Form_Load, you can see the form re-locating or re-sizing when it starts up. And that's not how you want to present your app to people. Looks a bit ... weird.

Comment: @ĈħőşęņŎńę, does this new app have a more complex control set then your previous applications? sound like a race condition between layout and setting the size/location

Comment: @sa_ddam213, not really more complex I don't think. It does have a very basic user control in it called an ActionBar (basically a crappy solid color menu with 4 pictureboxes as buttons). I wouldn't really call that complex. Besides that, theres a splitContainer and a MainMenu and a TextBox. That's it

Comment: @ĈħőşęņŎńę, so does it work correctly in `Shown` event, as you could just make the form invisible and make it visible in Shown after setting Size/Location.

Comment: Visual Studio has stopped responing. I am trying at the moment.

Comment: I just tried in Shown event, it is still bigger every time I open it.